# Why mysql throws "invalid default value for field" only when two or more timestamp fields exist in the create statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, timestamp, default-value

In mysql 5.7.28 I create a table like this:

```sql
create table t1 (
id int not null,
d1 timestamp) 
engine=innodb;
```

which **works fine** and creates `d1` as `non-null` with `default value current_timetamp`,`on update current_timestamp`.

But when I try to create the same table with a two timestamp fields as below:

```sql
create table t1 (
id int not null,
d1 timestamp,
d2 timestamp) 
engine=innodb;
```

I get an error:

> SQL error (1067): invalid default value for 'd2'

Why I get an error **only when I add a second timestamp** field?
Is this a bug or some expected behavior in mysql?

Comment: Never rely on default values. Always write the full specification for the field. Look [fiddle for MySQL 5.6](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3877e7391dd659fe15f596f5d69a7c3c), and while change DBMS version to 5.7 and to 8.0. *Why mysql ...* - by design.

Comment: `echo "bug" | wontfix`  : **feature**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is described in [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) system variable which is **by default disabled** for `5.6`,`5.7` (and effectively disabled on `5.1`) and it is **enabled** in `8.0`.

Quoting from above link:

> (5.7) If explicit_defaults_for_timestamp **is disabled**, the server enables
>   the nonstandard behaviors and handles TIMESTAMP columns as follows:
>
> - TIMESTAMP columns not explicitly declared with the NULL attribute are    automatically declared with the NOT NULL attribute. Assigning
>     such a    column a value of NULL is permitted and sets the column to
>     the    current timestamp.
> - The first TIMESTAMP column in a table, if not explicitly declared    with the NULL attribute or an explicit DEFAULT or ON UPDATE
>     attribute, is automatically declared with the DEFAULT
>     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attributes.
> - **TIMESTAMP columns following the first one, if not explicitly declared    with the NULL attribute or an explicit DEFAULT attribute,
>     are    automatically declared as DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'** (the
>     “zero”    timestamp). For inserted rows that specify no explicit value
>     for such    a column, the column is assigned '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and
>     no warning    occurs.
>
> Depending on whether **strict SQL mode or the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode is
>   enabled, a default value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' may be invalid**.

Now the issue with `5.7` is that `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode is enabled. This does **not allow** the default value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` which as described in the documentation would be added as default value (if not explicitly declared) in *timestamp columns following the first one*.

Mysql `8.0` still has the `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode enabled, but the `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` envvar is by default enabled which according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) it would add null as the default value see below (which will **not cause any errors on table creation** ):

> (8.0) If explicit_defaults_for_timestamp **is enabled**, the server disables the
>   nonstandard behaviors and handles TIMESTAMP columns as follows:
>
> [..]
>
> - TIMESTAMP columns not explicitly declared with the NOT NULL attribute are automatically declared with the NULL attribute and
>     permit NULL values. Assigning such a column a value of NULL sets it to
>     NULL, not the current timestamp.
>
> [..]
>
> - The first TIMESTAMP column in a table is not handled differently from TIMESTAMP columns following the first one.

This behavior has also been discussed on [MySQL's issue tracker](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80163) but has marked as "Not a bug".

As @Akina mentioned in comments, do not rely on default values. Always write the full specification for the field.